# How to convert a string column into a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imported a date column from a CSV file where there are string values are shown as

| date |
| --- |
| 44705 |
| 44704 |
| 44703 |

I want to convert the entire column into a date format as

| date |
| --- |
| "2022-05-22" |
| "2022-05-21" |
| "2022-05-20" |

I have used this script which allowed me to generate the result.

```sql
SELECT dateadd(d,44703,'1899-12-30') as date
```

The question is, how could I apply this script for a range of values (there are 700 rows in the table). e.g 44000 to 44705. I would like all string values to be converted as a date format.

Comment: Put your SQL in a select query against your table and use the column name?

Comment: Given you have a number column you won't be able to update it to hold a date time - you'll need a new column. Note for a date/datetime you don't store it with a format, you only format it to display it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a string to date we can add temporary date column and fill it and delete old column and rename new one to old one

```sql
alter table TableName add NewColumnName date null; --create temporary column
update TableName set NewColumnName =dateadd(d,cast(cast([date] as float) as int)-2,'1899-12-30') --fill it
alter table TableName drop column [date]--delete old column
EXEC sp_RENAME 'TableName.NewColumnName' , 'date', 'COLUMN'--rename new one to old one
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, would it be necessary to create a newcolumn name in the existing table before running this script? It returns with an invalid column under NewColumnName.

Comment: @clayton55 run each line one by one. ( I mean leave out first line. It has executed already :) )

Comment: the first line has been successful, the second line returns me with "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '44705.0' to data type int."

Comment: @clayton55 try `update TableName set NewColumnName =dateadd(d,cast(cast([date] as float) as int),'1899-12-30')`

Comment: @clayton55 I have updated answer 2nd query. Check once

Comment: hey @novice in DotNet, thanks for the help, there's an prompt error message stating is The column 'date2' is dependent on column 'date'. after running the second line

Comment: @clayton55 is date2 column **Computed Calculated** column?

Comment: the column "date2" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator, is there a way I could verify this?

Comment: @clayton55 then we have to remove Computed Column Specification Formula temporarily and add it lastly. No other go (In table design mode)

Comment: thanks for the advice @novice in DotNet, thus, should remove all the new temporally columns in design mode first, before running the script again?

Comment: @clayton55 exactly yep :)

Comment: alright i'll try it again now

Comment: i've deleted all of the temporally columns in design mode but the prompt message for date2 still exists, "The column 'date2' is dependent on column 'date'."

Comment: @clayton55 in table design mode click date2 column and expand Computed Column Specification and remove (Formula) property ( I mean check if it is necessary. Paste it in notepad :) )

Comment: great news @novice in DotNet! the script has progressed to the final stage. It states that there is a Syntax error parsing SQL identifier 'table.newcolumn'.

Comment: @clayton55 try `table.NewColumnName` it should be working then :)

Comment: @clayton55 Else Manually rename in design mode itself :)

Comment: @clayton55 I mean in table design mode click `NewColumnName` and type "date" and save table design :)

Comment: @clayton55 'table.newcolumn' I think table keyword is the issue. Replace by table's name

Comment: the solutions runs perfectly now, I can't thank you enough, I would like to accept your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast (44705-1 as smalldatetime) gives 2022-05-25 00:00
```

So you could just update the column using the above.

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dc24abb3025e0f3796e7d978ba406be3

New [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=004fd781ccddcc8bf89b225f06a9b693) with update statement, this line will update all rows, as per test.

```
update #test
set pdate = cast(dateadd(d,tdate-2,'1899-12-30') as smalldatetime)
```

Comment: this would transform the entire date column as "2022-05-25", but there are different string values in the dataset.

Comment: That was an example to show the formatted output, you would have to use the casting against the date column.

Comment: allow me to clarify, I could apply cast based on one string value. In this case, its 44705. If I would need to apply it against the date column, should I be using select cast (date as smalldatetime) ?